# Why is the x axis extended beyond the data in the reputation chart?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I just noticed a problem with the new SO design.

[image]

There isn't a line like the highlighted section above at the beginning of the chart, which makes me think that I haven't earned any reputations for the past two days.

Comment: post the reason for downvote?

Comment: Yeah that is kind of odd. As for the downvotes, many of the bug reports for the new design are getting downvoted for some reason.

Comment: Ah, a post about the new design. Well I have noticed that on my laptop that I now have an horizontal scrollbar and the layout no longer fits in screen, why is that and why hasn't it been designed with "responsive" in mind? Plus, is there an actual link that is talking about this?

Comment: @Fred: That *shouldn't* be a significant change -- the SE design has always been non-responsive, with a minimum assumed screen width of 1024 pixels. (There have been some display bugs on narrower screens that might have made it seem slightly flexible, but those are really glitches, not intended behavior.) If you want a fully responsive design for SE, try the mobile view.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I've been a member on Stack for a few years and have noticed a few changes, but unlike this one. I feel that Stack has enough resources and competent people on hand to implement a responsive method. After all, we are in 2015 and not 1994 when stylesheets only started surfacing. I'm sure Stack's looking over every post/comment and will most likely do a few touch-ups here and there. This is merely a comment and that is how Stack will get to see where the glitches are. If people do not say anything, how will they know where the bugs are, right? *Cheers*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The chart consists of 30 columns, each of them 13 pixels wide, with a gap of 2.5 pixels (yes, 2.5; I've no idea why they didn't pick a whole number) between them.  This gives the chart a total width of 13 × 30 + 2.5 × 29 = 462.5 pixels.

However, for some reason, the box enclosing the chart is styled to be 485 pixels wide, leaving an extra unused space of 22.5 pixels.

I see several possible ways to fix this:

1. Simply adjust the width of the enclosing box (`.user-rep-chart-summary` in CSS) down to, say, 465 pixels.
2. Remove the explicit width entirely (or set it to `width: auto`) and instead style the box as `display: inline-block`, which will cause it to resize to accommodate its content.
3. Increase the width of the chart columns, and/or the space between them.  For example, increasing the gap between the columns to 3px would make them take up a total of 477 pixels, which is close enough to 485 to leave no noticeable empty space.

Personally, **I would recommend option #3, possibly combined with #2.**
In particular, I suspect that the current 2.5 pixel margin between the columns may actually be causing the chart to look inconsistent between browsers, as some may be rounding the margin to a whole number of pixels, while other browsers may be using the exact subpixel measurement.  Rounding it up to a full 3 pixels should be safer.

The CSS changes to do this would look something like this:

```css
.user-show-new .user-rep-chart-summary .user-rep-chart-summary-tooltip {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 13px;
    margin-right: 3px;  /* <-- replaces previous "margin-right: 2.5px" */
}

.user-show-new .user-rep-chart-summary {
    display: inline-block;  /* <-- replaces previous "width: 485px" */
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

Comment: Why would you care if they didn't use a whole number margin for a graph?

Comment: @KyleMit Because a half-pixel is a very odd measure to use.

Comment: And because it's rendered as 2-3-2-3...

Comment: "In particular, I suspect that the current 2.5 pixel margin between the columns may actually be causing the chart to look inconsistent between browsers, as some may be rounding the margin to a whole number of pixels, while other browsers may be using the exact subpixel measurement." Do you have any reference that documents either behavior in a given browser? Subpixels always bug me in design and I would love to see such definitive documentation.

Answer (score 7):

I have pushed a fix for this based on Ilmari Karonen's solution #3. The change will go live after our next production build.