# Border under Featured tab is one pixel off in Firefox

Tags: bug, design, firefox

On Firefox the border under the Featured tab is lower than the rest of the line by one pixel.
[image: bad]
It looks OK on Chrome and Internet Explorer.

This is still not solved, and isn't a duplicate - this is specifically for Firefox, and the other question is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### 2015-03-14 Update

This isn't fixed yet. Oddly, it works *sometimes*, but sometimes it's still off. Here's one from today:

[image: still bad]

Comment: @HansPassant - Thanks, didn't see that one. But the other question is fox Chrome, my bug is in Firefox. Chromes seems OK.

Comment: Well, what are the odds.  Check again tomorrow.

Comment: Ah, the ritual Community ♦ bump. Well, no repro now on Firefox 36.0.1.

Comment: @Frédéric - This is till an issue for me sometimes, but not always. I've already accepted the site being ugly.

Comment: Hey wait, now it has disappeared on firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by fixing the counter's line height:

```css
#tabs a .bounty-indicator-tab {
    line-height: 1;
}
```

This change doesn't seem to break Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Comment: same, see [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283641/why-is-the-x-axis-extended-beyond-the-data-in-the-reputation-chart) question. Still i see a small line.