# Featured tab positioning

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The "featured" tab on stackoverflow looks slightly off:

[image]

as can be seen here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java

Seems to be broken on all major browsers on Windows.

Is that a recent change?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283957/border-under-featured-tab-is-one-pixel-off-in-firefox

Comment: @Kendra This seems to be related. This issue is in all browsers though, the linked question only on Firefox and cannot be fixed with the suggested solution.

Comment: This should be fixed with the latest build of our production server. Please let me know if you see any other problems with the bounty indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing

```
display: inline-block;
```

from the `bounty-indicator-tab` class style fixes it.