# Horizontal line under the "featured" tab disappears at certain screen resolutions

Tags: bug, design

Something I noticed lately and I'm not sure if anyone else also noticed, is a missing horizontal line at a (certain) lower screen size/resolution under the "featured" tab on [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)

When clicking on any other tab other than "featured", the horizontal line remains under all other tabs except for "featured".

I'm at 1280x600 and the line is missing right away when I'm in normal viewing mode (**no zooming**) and even at 1920x900 using the "Responsive Design Mode" in Firefox, the missing line under it still doesn't show.

However, when I zoom in using my mouse and roller (if I can say), only by zooming in on 2 clicks, the line appears, but disappears when I zoom in one more time and appears when zooming in one more time.

Is this a CSS bug or is that the intended styling? It seems a bit strange that it would be the way it was intended to be, given the line does appear at a certain viewing level.

I did find the following and other similar posts, but did not include/mention about it "missing/not showing":

- [Featured tab positioning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286787/featured-tab-positioning)

**Here are a few screenshots:** Note: The light gray line(s) *(with and without)* are very faint, therefore you will need to look at it very closely.

**Missing line:**

[image]

**Has line:**

[image]

- Being a stickler when it comes to (styling) detail, thought that this was worth addressing.

**Edit:**

I have one tower PC which runs on Windows 7 and the latest version of Firefox (50.0.2) and 2 laptops. The tower has the initial problem as does one of the laptops which is also on Windows 7 and the latest Firefox, but not the second laptop which I find rather bizarre, yet it runs on Linux Mint with Firefox 47.0.

This tells me that it isn't a coincidence.

Shouldn't that line be visible in any resolution, regardless of the DPI?

- I just tested this on IE 11, and it is OK. So this seems to be a browser specific issue, not DPI.

I'm waiting on a few people to tell me if this is also the case with them.

Comment: Only 100% zoom is supported. Design quirks that occur under other zoom levels won't be fixed.

Comment: @Stijn Even still, when I'm in normal viewing mode, the line isn't there as I feel it should be. The initial problem doesn't involve zooming.

Comment: Are you using a high DPI screen (retina display or whatever it's called)? Might be a bug for such screens.

Comment: @Stijn No, just a "run of the mill DELL" monitor. *Dell E176FPf 17" LCD Monitor*. Plus, I just checked on another machine being a laptop and it also does the same thing.

Comment: ...actually, 2 other laptops also.

Comment: I'm asking because your screenshots seem to indicate that you run on a higher DPI setting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJcct.png

Comment: @Stijn So basically, I should downgrade all my systems/screen resolutions? *lol* That doesn't make sense really. I'll try and get a second opinion from a few other people to see if they're seeing what I'm seeing (or not). The laptops (both of them) also do the same thing and they're not that new neither. I can't see this being a screen DPI issue. This wouldn't have anything to do with that last jQuery update would it? I know there were a lot of issues with that.

Comment: I didn't say that, did I? I only said that zooming is not supported. All my other comments are simply to help figure out under what circumstances the problem occurs.

Comment: @Stijn Let's take this from the top *lol* - I do not see the line that should be under "featured" when I am in normal viewing mode, meaning I did not zoom. The "zooming" part I talked about was to see if that line would appear in other viewing modes which it did, and that is what I find bizarre.

Comment: Fred, why aren't you using the new nav system?

Comment: @TravisJ What do you mean?

Comment: @Fred-ii- There is a new navigation feature, it has been in "alpha" for some time. I find it superior to the current "live" navigation. You can find it under your account settings, SITE SETTINGS -> Preferences and then scroll to the *very* bottom of the page and there is a checkbox you can check in order to use the new nav system.

Comment: Here is the original announcement for the new nav system: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing

Comment: @TravisJ Thanks a lot for that Travis, I didn't know about the beta nav system. I prefer the beta by far and for so many reasons, *cheers*